# CSS media queries different results

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styles, media-queries

Why is a DIV displaying different on mobile phone and a resized desktop window?

```
@media (max-width: 327px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
@media all and (min-width: 328px) and (max-width: 440px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
```

This is what I need... when viewed on desktop resized window it is ok, but on mobile phone it is not

Comment: Are you sure about `height: 0px !important;` again?

Comment: What is the resolution of the phone? It may well be more than `440px` wide

Comment: In both media queries the rule is the same, and I doubt that you really want `height: 0px;` you should use `@media (max-width: 327px) { ` if both rules are the same

Answer (score 2):

try to this

```css
.header{height:200px; width:200px; background:red;}
 @media (max-width: 327px) {
        .header  {height: 0px;}
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 440px) {
        .header  {height: 0px;}
    }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your phone width is more than 327px, so the rule is not active in your phone

Check this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Ok, so the width of my phone screen is 360px ... Height is shown... but on desktop, it is not (I resized to 360px)

Comment: Try replacing `height:0%` width `border: solid thin red` to check if height isn't working or the problem is the media query

Comment: Height is working... but it doesnt show the same... on mobile phone it is shown (extra ugly space) while on desktop it is ok... really strange..

Answer (score 1):

**!important** is a very bad thing in CSS, use selectors instead.

Read this: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

***Coming to your question***

> *Change:*

```
@media (max-width: 327px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
@media all and (min-width: 328px) and (max-width: 440px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
```

> *To:*

```
@media all and (max-width: 327px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 328px) and (max-width: 440px) { 
    .header  {height: 0px !important;}
}
```

Comment: If the above code doesn't work, then inspect element and see what is being overridden, there maybe some styling from other styles sheet which is doing this.